# DHCP server(s) IP allocation based on device type

Tags: router, dhcp

In my study lab, I connect my pc to an Ethernet port wall socket and get a following IP allocation

> 192.168.1.X/24 Gateway: 192.168.1.1

but if I connect a standalone rogue wifi router's wan port to the same socket I get a different IP network configuration

> 192.168.29.X/24 Gateway:192.168.29.1

Is there anything different in terms of DHCP DISCOVER broadcast between PC and router and how exactly is the dhcp server(s) differentiates between the two. Or have I figured this out totally wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The DHCP server might give IPs based on MAC adress

```
subnet 192.0.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option routers 192.0.2.1;

  # Unknown clients get this pool.
  pool {
    option domain-name-servers bogus.example.com;
    max-lease-time 300;
    range 192.0.2.200 192.0.2.253;
    allow unknown-clients;
  }

  # Known clients get this pool.
  pool {
    option domain-name-servers ns1.example.com, ns2.example.com;
    max-lease-time 28800;
    range 192.0.2.5 192.0.2.199;
    deny unknown-clients;
  }
}

host myhost1 { hardware ethernet 01:23:45:00:00:01; }
host myhost2 { hardware ethernet 01:23:45:00:00:02; }
host myhost3 { hardware ethernet 01:23:45:00:00:03; }
```

Comment: Both devices are personal not known to the  network previously.

Comment: And in this case the pools are different network not different subnets.